# why require login when already add cookie on browser?

Tags: php, cookies, browser, web

I login to website successfully and cookie add in browser for that website
but 1 day later, I enter this website so website require me login although I check cookie still available 
somebody can help me to explain in this case !
P/S:this website use PHP source. in case appear in some other PHP website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what it sounds like is happening is that the session cookie (the cookie used to authenticate you) expired. Cookies are often set to expire to log you out of a given application for security reasons (to prevent cases such as someone else using your computer and accessing your banking details because the cookie didn't expire and you didn't explicitly click  log out).

Comment: I checked expire all cookie on site. Date expired is still available, them no expired, guy @winhowes

Comment: There's a number of things that could happen here. The cookie might not have to expire, but they could expire your session on the server-side. Basically, they could see if someone using that session had done anything in a certain period of time and if it hadn't, they'd clear that session from their database. You'd still have the cookie, but they wouldn't know who to associate that with.

Comment: what do you mean by "solve this case"? What are you trying to accomplish? Not being logged out? If what I proposed is correct, then to not be logged out, you would need to be making active requests to the site every-so-often to prevent your session from timing out

Comment: my mean I do not want to log in everyday.when i log in the first and got cookie and everytime later I will enter website that do not login

Comment: how your mean "making active requests" ? @winhowes

Comment: You could write a script that sends your cookie to the site and takes some action. Basically, you (either you or a script using your cookie) have to take some action frequently on the site in order to prevent your session from expiring. At the end of the day though, you don't really have a lot of control over this. If the site would like to log you out after a certain period of time, they can do so and there's nothing you can about that

Comment: yes, @winhowes. I am writing application to scraping websites, I add cookie for site but when applicaition run so can not get content website after log in successfully. I use C# httpwebrequest